# Making plots of intermediate results from sci.py least_squares

Tags: python, optimization, plot, least-squares

In sci.py least_squares, I want to use Levenberg-Marquardt method to compute the minimum of the Rosenbrock function, and I see that it gives me the correct minimum and takes 108 iterations.
[image]

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to get the intermediate iterations, and plot them. How should I do this?

I tried to read the sci.py page, but I didn't really get an anser there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I would like to know is if it is possible to list all the iterations, since the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is iterative.